# How can I determine if user have sent an email or not

Tags: android, email

In my app I need to send an mail with some attachments. I know I can call `new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);`, it's OK with that thing. The problem is: I need to know whether user have sent an email, or not. In iOS to implement this thing I should just use `MFMailComposeViewControlle` from where I can check if mail was sent. How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot reliably find out if the user sent an email, or if the user modified the email, via `ACTION_SEND`. Whether the user sends the email is up to the user and the email client, since this is the user's device, the user's email account, the user's bandwidth, etc.

If your application needs to control enough aspects of sending the email, enough to know for certain if it was sent, send the email yourself (JavaMail, Web service, etc.).